# can not use sqoop for import data tables into hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I want to import data tables from [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) to [hbase](/questions/tagged/hbase) via [sqoop](/questions/tagged/sqoop). So, i downloaded `sqoop-1.4.4.tar.gz`, extracted it, and added `jdbc.jar` file into `/lib`.

Then I set `SQOOP_HOME` and `PATH` and save them in `bash.bashrc`.
When I run `which sqoop` reply me `/usr/local/sqoop/bin/sqoop`

But when I am writing 'sqoop help' gives me the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/sqoop/Sqoop
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop. Program will exit.
```

Please guide me how I can solve it and how I can import data tables into hbase.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Sqoop libraries to the classpath and see if it helps.

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$SQOOP_HOME/lib
```

Comment: thanks for your help,when i run 'sqoop help' it show the command but show:/usr/local/Sqoop/bin/configure-sqoop: line 68: to: command not found. how solved it

Comment: please guide me on my mail: asma.zeidabadi@gmail.com